# Schema for complex sequence generation and storage

Tags: mongodb, schema, mongoose

I have a database with a customer table. These customers are businesses, and I'm trying to design a flexible, reliable way that allows the customer to design his own custom invoice numbers.

For example:

- Customer A Invoice Sequence: A-1306-1234, where 'A-' is static text, 1306 is YYMM, and 1234 is a sequence that resets every month
- Customer B Invoice Sequence: 123456 - This is a sequence that just counts forever
- Customer C Invoice Sequence: 13-123456 - This sequence has YY- and then the sequence runs for a year and resets.

I'm trying to decide of the most flexible way to allow somewhat arbitrary sequences to become parts of this number.  I also need to generate this number atomically and handle the reset of the sequence based on the inherent rules the individual elements impose, such as MM in the sequence infers that the pure incremental restarts each month, where MMDD infers that the pure incremental element restarts each day.

Are custom Types the correct way?  A set of getters and setters along with statics and methods and validators? Is there already a design pattern for this type of feature?

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve a problem similar to your case for Customer B.
My solution: I created a collection to store sequences and added a document like this:

```
{
 "_id" : "PIN",
 "_class" : "com.alldata.genIII.bo.Sequence",
 "description" : "Sequence for PIN numbers. Used in all Account collections. ",
 "nextValue" : NumberLong(100001)

}
```

I use the _id to specify the field in the Account collection that will use the sequence. I started it in 100001 for user requirements.

When creating accounts, I fetch the next value of the sequence and update the sequence adding 1.
This operation is atomic because I use [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/).

This is my code (in java) to fetch the next value of the sequence:

```
    public Long fetchNextValue(String sequenceId) {
        Update update = new Update();
        update.inc("nextValue", 1);
        Sequence seq = mongoTemplate.findAndModify(new Query(Criteria.where("code").is(sequenceId)), update, Sequence.class);
        if (seq == null)
            throw new NotFoundException("Sequence not found for sequenceId " + sequenceId);
        return seq.getNextValue();
    }
```

I have this code running in production and so far I haven't have problems. But just in case, I put a unique index in the "pin" field of the accounts collection so if there's a duplicate, I'd catch the exception and retry a couple of times with a new pin.

For more info on how to accomplish this take a look at this [article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

For your other cases, you could use a javascript function stored in mongoDB that applies that logic to the sequence. Take a look at this [article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/), although now there's a message saying they don't recommend it (that message is new...) but it could give you more ideas.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the links. Since the input will be user-entered, eval() is out unless I do some rigorous filtering on the input, or force the user to us some sort of UI to build the format srting.

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished my goal with a much simpler solution than I set out to find. In each agency record, I created a String field called `invoice_format`. In this field, I store a format string that I parse to generate an invoice number.  For example:

```
invoice_format: "A-{YY}{seq-04.d}"
```

I parse this and anything inside {} is considered a formatting rule, and anything outside {} is considered literal text.  I have a not-so-glamorous switch that looks up each formatting rule and returns a value based on the rule. I still have work to do, but this forms the basis of my sequence generator. The sequence for each customer is kept in a separate field, called invoice_sequence, and when I encounter {seq} in a field, I increment this field and return the result.